# INNER JOIN SQL query conversion nvarchar value to int

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use an `INNER JOIN` in SQL to show a column from one table into another. Here is the query that I'm using:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person.BusinessEntity 
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee ON Person.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID = HumanResources.Employee.JobTitle
```

When I execute this, I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Chief Executive Officer' to data type int

I'm not trying to convert the data so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to convert an ID (int data type) to their job title (nvarchar datatype). What results are you wanting to get?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the Job Title column to appear in the business Entity table. After the businessEntityID column.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to join to columns with different data types you are forcing the database to make an implicit conversion which it can't do in this case. What you want to do is to join the tables on the keys the share (which would be BusinessEntityID in this case).

The table and column names look familiar and I'm guessing that you are following the examples in the book *Beginning Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Programming* (or some similar book that uses the AdventureWorks sample database) and if so the source of the issue is that you are using the wrong column in the HumanResources.Employee table. It should be

```
SELECT Person.BusinessEntity.*, HumanResources.Employee.JobTitle
FROM Person.BusinessEntity 
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee
  ON Person.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID = HumanResources.Employee.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: Trying this now. I'll let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I think type of column BusinessEntityID is INT while the type of column JobTitle is NVARCHAR. So this:

```
    ON Person.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID = HumanResources.Employee.JobTitle
```

is equals to:

```
    ON 1 = 'Chief...Officer'
```

And you can't compare an int with a NVARCHAR, both must be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

In case `HumanResources.Employee.JobTitle` has mixed data, number and char-
I will resolve it, by using a

```
WHERE HumanResources.Employee.JobTitle!= CHAR
```

for example.